# How to pass an updated variable to another component without reloading the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, service

I am not sure whether such question exists because I dont exactly know what the concept I am looking for is named by.
So I have a shared-service:

```
// shared.service.ts
public showLoginForm: boolean = true;
```

In my app.component I use the variable from above as follows:

```
//app.component.ts
ngOnInit: void {
    this.showLoginForm = this.sharedSrv.showLoginForm;
}
```

Now, in my login.component I change the variable in my service without leaving the app.component view:

```
// login.component.ts
login(f: ngForm){
...

this.sharedSrv.showLoginForm = false;
}
```

How do I pass the new value of `showLoginForm`to the app component?

Comment: You need to use a BehaviorSubject to watch for changes to that service variable. You can then subscribe to those changes within your component. This is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545856/how-to-watch-service-variable-in-angular-6/51545989

Comment: Thank you for sharing a helpful link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `showLoginForm` as an Observable stream something like `shared.service.ts`

```
    private showLoginFormSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.showLoginFormSubject = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  }

  setShowLoginForm(show: boolean) {

    this.showLoginFormSubject.next(show);
  }

  getShowLoginForm(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.showLoginFormSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

now in the component: `login.component.ts`

```
this.sharedSrv.getShowLoginForm().subscribe(val=>this.showLoginForm=val);
```

to update the value:

```
this.sharedSrv.setShowLoginForm(false);
```

Comment: Now, I really understood how BehaviorSubject works!

Comment: There are a few typos in the code. will edit it now.